# Merge (inner join) in Lodash keeping only rows with common keys

Tags: javascript, merge, filtering, lodash

Trying to combine the return of two APIs using lodash, I've managed to join common fields in them using merge:

```
var primaryCount = [
    {id: 0, name: "foo", address: "one"},
    {id: 1, name: "bar", address: "two"},
];
var secondaryCount = [
    {franchise_id: 1, count:4},
  {franchise_id: 3, count:16},
]

var merged = _.merge(_.keyBy(primaryCount, 'id'), _.keyBy(secondaryCount, 'franchise_id'));
var values = _.values(merged);
```

However I need to only items where both fields `id` and `franchise_id` defined. However it yields fields that are only present in one of them (I want only `id:1`):

```
[
   {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "foo",
      "address": "one"
   },
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "bar",
      "address": "two",
      "franchise_id": 1,
      "count": 4
   },
   {
      "franchise_id": 3,
      "count": 16
   }
]
```

I tried using filter like this, but it returns an empty array for both:

```
var leftFiltered = _.filter(values, ['id', null]);
var rightFiltered = _.filter(leftFiltered, ['franchise_id', undefined]);
```

How can I make an inner merge like this?

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "bar",
      "address": "two",
      "franchise_id": 1,
      "count": 4
   },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your custom filtering & mapping logic or use something like [lodash-joins](https://github.com/mtraynham/lodash-joins#inner-joins)

```
#### Example:
> var _ = require('index.js');
> var left = [
...       {id: 'c', left: 0},
...       {id: 'c', left: 1},
...       {id: 'e', left: 2},
...   ],
...   right = [
...       {id: 'a', right: 0},
...       {id: 'b', right: 1},
...       {id: 'c', right: 2},
...       {id: 'c', right: 3},
...       {id: 'd', right: 4},
...       {id: 'f', right: 5},
...       {id: 'g', right: 6}
...   ],
...   accessor = function (obj) {
...       return obj['id'];
...   };
>
> var a = _.hashInnerJoin(left, accessor, right, accessor);
undefined
> a
[ { id: 'c', left: 0, right: 2 },
  { id: 'c', left: 1, right: 2 },
  { id: 'c', left: 0, right: 3 },
  { id: 'c', left: 1, right: 3 } ]
>
> var b = _.nestedLoopLeftOuterJoin(left, accessor, right, accessor);
undefined
> b
[ { id: 'c', left: 0, right: 2 },
  { id: 'c', left: 0, right: 3 },
  { id: 'c', left: 1, right: 2 },
  { id: 'c', left: 1, right: 3 },
  { id: 'e', left: 2 } ]
>
> var c = _.sortedMergeFullOuterJoin(left, accessor, right, accessor);
undefined
> c
[ { id: 'a', right: 0 },
  { id: 'b', right: 1 },
  { id: 'c', left: 0, right: 2 },
  { id: 'c', left: 0, right: 3 },
  { id: 'c', left: 1, right: 2 },
  { id: 'c', left: 1, right: 3 },
  { id: 'd', right: 4 },
  { id: 'e', left: 2 },
  { id: 'f', right: 5 },
  { id: 'g', right: 6 } ]
```

Comment: I didn't know about this lib, using `hashInnerJoin` with two different acessor functions (one for each "side" of the join) solved my problem, thanks!